# Codeigniter - in view while foreach-ing get row count from another table by id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have Categories Controller - index

```
public function index()
    {

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY priority");
        $this->_viewdata['categories'] = $query->result();
        //-- I will use model for mysql queries!

        $this->load->view('admin/categories', $this->_viewdata);
    }
```

In view Im printing results using foreach:

```
<?php
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
?>
       Name: <?=$category->name;?> // and etc...
       Subcategories: // <- I want to get subcats count for every category by its id (where catid='$category->id') like this
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

I have another table called "subcategories" and I have "catid" column inside it. And I want to get every Subcategories count by Category and display it inside view. How can I do this?

Comment: You would have to join subcategories to your sql statement. `SELECT * FROM categories c JOIN subcategories s ON s.catid = c.id ORDER BY c.priority`

Comment: when I use this query how can I get subcats ->count and categories ->result separately?

Comment: @NurlanXp, What You should be asking yourself "Oh when I do that, what am I getting? I know, I'll do a var_dump on $this->_viewdata['categories'] and see what comes out." Or even run the SQL in phpmyadmin and inspect the results from there...

Comment: Indeed, don't knock it till you try it. That's what troubleshooting is... Try and failing, seeing what you need and what you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comments what I would do is Join the tables like:

```
SELECT * FROM categories c JOIN subcategories s ON s.catid = c.id ORDER BY c.priority
```

Or since you are using Codeigniter you could even use:

```
$this->db->join('subcategories', 'subcategories.catid = categories.id');
```

Then I would save the subcats to a different array and iterate through those.

```
<?php
    $newCategories;
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
      if($category->name != $cat){
       //New category
       $cat = $category->name;
       $newCategories[$cat][] = $category;
      }
      else{
       $newCategories[$cat][] = $category;
      }
    }
    foreach($newCategories as $name => $cat){
?>
       Name: <?php echo $name ?>.
       Subcategories: <?php 
                       foreach($cat as $sub){
                        echo $sub->..; //Fill in your template
                       }
                      ?>
```

I'm sure it can be done better though.